# SharedPreferences simply not loading data, even within same instance of app

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

This is in my `onCreate`:

```
sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
```

`sharedPrefs` being an uninitialized `SharedPreferences` in the class.

Later, I do this:

```
sharedPrefs.edit().putString("token", token);
Log.d("asdf", "token is " + token);
Log.d("asdf", "reading prefs: " + sharedPrefs.getString("token", null));
```

And the log output is as follows:

```
token is ABC123
reading prefs: null
```

So `token` (a string) is definitely getting set correctly. But for some reason.. it just won't save/read in the sharedPreferences.

Any ideas? I'll post the full code if you guys want, but I doubt it'll help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After the `put()` method, you should implement `sharedPrefs.edit().commit()` to commit the data into the sharedpreference.

```
sharedPrefs.edit().putString("token", token)
                .commit();
```